# Phonegap enable gps services

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

Im writting a phonegap app that uses gps. I want to be able to redirected to gps settings so that i can switch it on. how can i achieve that. All the previous articles show how to enable gps at run time and the code is deprecated.

Comment: as with anything on Cordova/Phonegap use a plugin. Read the [new documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/index.html). Near is the bottom is a link to Geolocation (GPS). Follow it. -- This FAQ should also help. Read the **bold** sentences first. [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

Comment: Why is my question getting a negative remark?

Comment: Your question is an FAQ question. This means you are lazy.

Comment: Your comment is useless shoud have kept quite instead

Comment: One day you will be fired from your job. What will you say then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after struggling for a while i found a plugin that was able to help me with my problem.

http://devpost.com/software/cordova-dialog-gps

```
  function calldialog() {
  document.addEventListener("deviceready",function() {
  cordova.dialogGPS("Your GPS is Disabled, this app needs to be enable to      works.",//message
                "Use GPS, with wifi or 3G.",//description
                function(buttonIndex){//callback
                  switch(buttonIndex) {
                    case 0: break;//cancel
                    case 1: break;//neutro option
                    case 2: break;//user go to configuration
                  }},
                  "Please Turn on GPS",//title
                  ["Cancel","Later","Go"]);//buttons
 });
 }
```

Comment: This plugin is outdated and worked only with android

Answer (score 2):

Specifically for Android, you could use [cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy) to switch on/increase accuracy of Location services from within your app (similar to how Google Maps does it).

This avoids needing to switch to the Location settings page and have the user manually change Location mode to enable GPS.

Comment: Thanks i will be sure to try it